# No attribute "ZipFile" in "pandas.io.common"

Tags: python, anaconda

I am running the code below (which used to work completely fine on my other PC) on my jupyter notebook

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.common import ZipFile
from requests import get
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy import sparse
from scipy import linalg
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
from collections import namedtuple
import sys
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

### but it gives me this error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call    last)
<ipython-input-16-16e4444bee4f> in <module>()
  1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 from pandas.io.common import ZipFile
  3 from requests import get
  4 
  5 import numpy as np

ImportError: cannot import name ZipFile
```

It seems my pandas.io.common module doesn't have ZipFile attribute.. 
I really appreciate if someone could help me in fixing this problem (I'm using anaconda2 on ubuntu).

Comment: See if [this Github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/280) is relevant

Comment: What version of anaconda and host os is this for?  I just tried it on windows with anaconda3 4.4.0 (pandas v0.20.1) and ZipFile is not included in the package.  The common.py in 20.x doesn't appear to have ZipFile https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.20.x/pandas/io/common.py. Where did you find the original example using ZipFile?

Comment: The Pandas (0.18.0) has this attribute. I installed it and now the code is  working.